# Is inversion always considered formal?

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

When using conditionals:

> *Had I seen him,* I would've told him.

When using emphasis:

> *Rarely did we* arrive on time.

Is **inversion** always considered formal when speaking or writing?

Comment: There's quite a difference in register, I think, between "Had I seen..." and "Rarely did we...".The latter would sound stilted in most casual conversations, but the former is widely used. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Had+I+been%2CIf+I+had+been&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHad%20I%20been%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIf%20I%20had%20been%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Interesting. They almost overlap.

Comment: @TRomano It's interesting that you say that, since my reaction was the opposite. I can't imagine hearing the first example in conversation, while using inversion for emphasis sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: @Era: I don't think it's just my "ear" here. The inversion of the "Rarely were we" variety is considerably more rarified than "We were rarely.." but both forms of the hypothetical (If I had known, Had I known) are almost on a par with each other. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Rarely+were+we%2CWe+were+rarely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRarely%20were%20we%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWe%20were%20rarely%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano I disagree with your assessment. First, you are looking at *literary* usage, not verbal usage. Second, I would certainly expect the more emphatic form to be **much** rarer. If it were the norm, it would not be emphatic. It would be stilted indeed if someone used this construction in every other sentence, but if someone said it it would not faze me. On the other hand, *had I seen him* would be jarring for me to hear in casual conversation, and to me sounds stilted even in writing. More to the point, though, is that you need more evidence that your interpretation of the data is valid.

Comment: @Era:  I don't have time find a spoken-text-base and try to suss this out, so let's leave it at two native speakers (or so I assume) disagreeing on register, neither of whom has given sufficient evidence to convince the other, though at least I have tried. I grant you your point that Google's ngram is of limited value.  I use the "Had I|we|you|they ..." hypothetical construction in casual conversation but would never say "Rarely have I ...." , and for you it seems to be just the opposite.

Comment: @TRomano could you post an answer along these lines? Currently the question is still in the unanswered list even though Subjunctive seems pretty satisfied the the answer given in your comment

Comment: @jfhc: User Era has a valid point that Google ngrams are hardly the best evidence for spoken registers, so it's probably for the best that it be kept as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inversion is mainly used for emphasis, whether it is in the form of (auxiliary verb +subject) after certain words or expressions such as:
a) Rarely do we see any tourists in this part of the country.

b) Never have we heard such an interesting speech.

Or weather it is a conditional sentence:

a) Had you listened to my advice, you would have passed the exam.
(There are other structures, not need to be mentioned here)

These structures are used in formal English, according to grammar books, but are also heard in everyday conversations.